# Force switching Input Method

Tags: java, android, android-input-method

I wonder if there is a way to force switching between actives InputMethod from an external app.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, this is not possible, for security and usability reasons.

Comment: Actually I found the method setInputMethod(..) from the InputMethodManager class and using the WRITE_SECURE_CONFIG it is possibile to change the current input manager, the problem is the "refresh". The system doesn't refresh the Input Manager until you provide some further tap-tap to the screen.

Comment: @Federico: There is no `WRITE_SECURE_CONFIG` in Android.